# URL address of local file not working

Tags: url

I'm trying to upload a photo to a Blogger widget. I have the code: *(I changed the angle brackets for curly brackets)*

```
{a href="http://company.com/ampers"}
{img src="~/Desktop/picture.png" /}extra wording here{/a}
```

This doesn't work.

I've also tried `~/Home/Desktop/picture.png`

Any suggestions? I have searched the web but am probably not wording my question correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You just can't link an image from your computer directly in Blogger or any website. Why? Easy: because NOBODY would be able to see the data. Let me explain.

1. `~` represent the user's folder. If Blogger would let you add it, **the path would change between every device**, including the server where the website is hosted! *(yep, websites are stored in computers like yours)*
2. Even if that worked, you wouldn't be able to see the image from another device. That happends because **you're not sharing your computer's content to the entire Internet** (if your computer does, then it's a server). You would need to set up complicated things like Apache, DNS or port forwarding.

So then, how do you add your photo to the Blogger widget? That's simple: use a service such [imgur](http://imgur.com) or [postimage](http://postimage.org), then get the direct link or URL of your image.

P.S.: OK, I answered some months late and you may solved the problem... but hey, I'm trying to help!

Answer (score 1):

Try `src="file:///home/USERNAME/Desktop/picture.png"` - which you can see when you open the image in your browser.